# How to have section name before table?

Tags: tabularx, debian

I am thinking how to have the section name before the table. 
I think I need to use possibly `float`. 
Code which output in Fig. 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\section*{Abbreviations}

    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | l}
    \textit{Abbreviation} & \textit{Definition} \\ \hline
    EHF & Ebola Hemorrhagic Fever (deprecated) \\
    EVD & Ebola Virus Disease (current) \\ 
    IP & Incubation period \\ 
    GP & Glycoprotein \\
    VHF & Viral Hemmorrhagic Fever \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Since you don't use that `table` is a float, it should be enough to comment out `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`. The problem here is that `table` floats to before the section heading.

Comment: In addition to @StefanH: If you want to use a caption for a table outside of a float, the `capt-of`-package or KOMA-Script classes provide the `\captionof{environment}[toc entry]{caption}` command.

Comment: By the way, you don't even need a tabular for this. If the section title is “Abbreviations” and then a list of acronyms appear, readers will know how to interpret it without telling them about “abbreviation” and “definition”.

Comment: Additionally IMHO you shouldn't use the vertical line in a simple table like this one.

Comment: By the way, "depreciated" should be "deprecated". To depreciate is to lose value over time; to deprecate something is to say that it shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: Why not using a package like `acro`, `acronyms` or `glossaries` for such list of abbrevations?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need solution which works in essays and Beamer presentations. I need to think more about your proposals. Can you extend it as an answer and explain which of those packages is most suitable for the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need that `tabular` or similar must go in a `table` environment. Your instance is not a float, so no `table`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\section*{Abbreviations}

\noindent              
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X}
\textit{Abbreviation} & \textit{Definition} \\ \hline
EHF & Ebola Hemorrhagic Fever (depreciated) \\
EVD & Ebola Virus Disease (current) \\
IP & Incubation period \\
GP & Glycoprotein \\
VHF & Viral Hemmorrhagic Fever
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Note that `tabularx` needs at least one `X` column.

On the other hand, I don't think that `tabularx` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Abbreviations}

\begin{description}

\item[EHF] Ebola Hemorrhagic Fever (depreciated)
\item[EVD] Ebola Virus Disease (current)
\item[IP] Incubation period
\item[GP] Glycoprotein
\item[VHF] Viral Hemmorrhagic Fever

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should mention that it's possible to customize the `description` with `enumitem` to look like a table.

Comment: @TeXnician You did it. `;-)` Besides, I don't think it should look like a table.

Comment: Is it ok not to include the heading: *abbreviation* and *definition*? Any formal policy here? The last one looks great. I like the simplicity a lot.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - Indeed, if it's obvious to the reader what the tabular material is all about, the header row may be omitted safely.

Answer (score 4):

If the list of abbreviations is quite long, consider using a `longtable` environment instead of either a `tabularx` or a `tabular` environment. This will allow for automatic page breaks, if and where needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\section*{Abbreviations}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % left-align rather than center-set the longtable
\begin{longtable}{@{}l p{0.75\textwidth}@{}}
\textit{Abbreviation} & \textit{Definition} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
EHF & Ebola Hemorrhagic Fever (depreciated) \\
EVD & Ebola Virus Disease (current) \\ 
IP  & Incubation period \\ 
GP  & Glycoprotein \\
VHF & Viral Hemmorrhagic Fever \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should adjust your `p{0.75\textwidth}` to span the whole line, e.g. with `\setbox1\hbox{\textit{Abbreviation}} \newdimen\mywidth \mywidth=\textwidth \advance\mywidth by -\wd1 \advance\mywidth by -2\tabcolsep` and then using `p{\mywidth}` for the column definition.

Comment: @Skillmon - Thanks. I thought about doing just what you suggest, but then I didn't feel sure that's really the best approach. If none of the text strings in the "Definition" column are all that long (and, in particular, don't require a line break), using `l` instead of `p{0.75\textwidth}` may be the best solution. Maybe the OP will provide more information about what kind of material will end up being placed in the "Definition" column.

Comment: In this case one could write a macro which checks the width of the entire table while using the `l` approach and then check whether the width is wider than `\textwidth` and based on this decide whether to use the `l` or the `p{\mywidth}` approach. But this might be over the top :)

Comment: @Skillmon - More thanks. :-) I've noticed that the OP has already "accepted" another answer; we may never find out how desirable it is to make the `longtable` occupy the full width of the text block.

Comment: Sad but true. While I really would have liked this approach :) I think I'll try to create a versatile macro trying to accomplish this. But my time right now is limitted and I might not be experienced enough yet to create a package like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it as a floating environment, then use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

    \section*{Abbreviations}

    \begin{table}[ht]%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l | X}
            \textit{Abbreviation} & \textit{Definition} \\ \hline
            EHF & Ebola Hemorrhagic Fever (depreciated) \\
            EVD & Ebola Virus Disease (current) \\ 
            IP & Incubation period \\ 
            GP & Glycoprotein \\
            VHF & Viral Hemmorrhagic Fever \\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, using it without the `table` environment makes more sense here.

Comment: Confirmed. This works.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 it works most of the time but not necessarily. If TeX thinks it doesn't fit beneath the caption it will still float to the top of a page. You might add an exclamation mark to the `[ht]` like this `[!ht]` to make it work even more often.

Comment: With a exclamation mark you have some more changes to the internal setting of floating objects.